# nginx proxy pass redirected to url

Tags: nginx

I have certain app running on port 8585. Every time I hit **localhost:8585**, it will redirect me to **localhost:8585/ui/home/**.

Now I'm trying to setup nginx proxy_pass for this, so every time I hit **localhost/myapp** it should redirect to **localhost:8585**.

This is my setup:

```
location /myapp/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8585/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Now, everytime I hit **localhost/myapp**, the url is changed to **localhost/ui/home/** and returns 404.

What is the correct setup for achieve this?

Comment: You should not use `proxy_redirect off;` you should try `proxy_redirect http://localhost:8585/ $host/myapp/;`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Check if the redirect is server based or javascript based

Comment: I don't have access to source code app on 8585. Hmmm, this also happens when I try to set nginx proxy to kibana (default kibana is run on localhost:5601/app/kibana, but I want to set localhost/kibana to point to kibana)

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am facing the same issue with hbase application in EMR.